# Android : Programmatically contact is syncing with my web server

Tags: android, json, web-services, synchronization, contacts

I get my phone all contact in Json format. But how to sync all contact in my own web server ?
Like I will create google sync.

Comment: what did you try still ??

Comment: any android phone to get contact and sync to my web server like google